# Do foods rich in antioxidants prevent avocado guacamole from turning brown?

Tags: mexican-cuisine, avocados

My guacamole (diced tomatos, onion, garlic and avocado) often turns brown.

I have read that the brown color on avocados is caused by oxidation.

In other words, exposure to the air turns avocado flesh from green to brown.

Will anti-oxidant rich foods, such as gogi berries, prevent my guacamole from turning brown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The antioxidants in food work on cell level in the human body. They are a vastly diverse group of minerals, vitamins and other chemical compounds.<sup>1</sup>

The oxidation that turns guacamole and other foods brown, is a chemical reaction with oxygen from the surrounding air affecting the surface.

The best way to prevent this discoloration is to minimize exposure to air (cling film on the surface works surprisingly well) and adding citrus juice - for guacamole a generous dose of lime should work, particularly if drizzled or sprayed on, not stirred in.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that questions and discussion about health are explicitly of topic. We deal with food, not the human body.

Comment: I don't think your implication that antioxidants don't mitigate browning from atmospheric oxygen is true; oxygen is an oxidant (heck, it's why we *call* them *oxi*dants) like any other, and it interacts with antioxidants like any other.

Your point about excluding air from the guacamole being effective is absolutely true, but your suggestion to add citrus juice, particularly as a surface treatment, is a good one precisely because the vitamin C in citrus is an excellent antioxidant.